# how to fix acute-select.js source code to resolve code minification issue?

Tags: angularjs, bundling-and-minification

Acute select directive produces [Injector Unknown Provider error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=nProvider%20%3C-%20n) while doing code minification.

> 'Inline array annotations' are not properly implemented in the acute select directive [(source code)](https://github.com/john-oc/acute-select/blob/master/acute/acute.select/acute.select.js).

I have tried to rewrite the source code by adding inline array annotations but still i get the same error.

Whats wrong in the source code? How to fix it?

[**Updated**]

**Solution:** [Modified Acute Select File](https://github.com/jsowndarrajan/AcuteSelectMinifyIssue/blob/master/AccuteSelectMinifyIssue/Scripts/vendor/acute.select/acute.select.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make below change for every controller, directive, service, provider, factory

```
controller: function($scope, $element, $window, $rootScope, $timeout, $filter, navKey, safeApply)
```

change above to

```
controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$window', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$filter', 'navKey', 'safeApply', function($scope, $element, $window, $rootScope, $timeout, $filter, navKey, safeApply){......}]
```

Comment: Try "use strcit" in every JavaScript file. So that you would know all syntactical mistakes before compressing it.

Comment: You are right. Array inline annotation is the only way to fix this problem.!